# C# Error when updating

Tags: c#, sql

So working on a project currently and stuck on this problem

When I try to update an item in the SQL database I keep getting an error and kind of stumped as to the error.

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Do You Wish To Update Field Details?", "Update Field Details", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
{
    try
    {
        int fieldID = int.Parse(cmbFieldInfo.SelectedValue.ToString());

        drFields = dsFarmCosts.Tables["fieldDetails"].Rows.Find(fieldID);

        drFields.BeginEdit();
        drFields["fieldName"] = add.FieldName;
        drFields["fieldSize"] = add.FieldSize;
        drFields["FieldLocation"] = add.FieldLocation;
        drFields["fieldHistory"] = add.FieldHistory;
        drFields.EndEdit();
        daFarmCosts.Update(dsFarmCosts, "fieldDetails");

        Reset();

        MessageBox.Show("Field Details Updated");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Error is

> System.InvalidOperationException: Update requires a valid
>   UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.
>
> at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs
>   rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
>
> at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs
>   rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
>
> at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows,
>   DataTableMapping tableMapping)
>
> at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable
>   dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
>
> at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataSet dataSet, String
>   srcTable)
>
> at Farm_Costs.field_screens.fieldEditScreen.btnSubmit_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in H:\School\Magee\Project\Programme\Farm
>   Costs\Farm Costs\field screens\fieldEditScreen.cs:line 114

Amy advice or tips?

Comment: Well, exception text is self-explanatory. Have you configured `UpdateCommand` of your `daFarmCosts` dataadapter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an `UpdateCommand` on the `daFarmCosts` DataAdapter. Something similar to the following code:

```
...
daFarmCosts .Fill();
dadaFarmCosts UpdateCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(daFarmCosts).GetUpdateCommand();
...
daFarmCosts .Update();
```

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly. 

Assume delete will also be similar then?

Comment: If you have populated a DataSet, you can delete the rows in the DataSet and then Update the DataAdapter with you DataSet. This way the rows will get deleted

Comment: Thank you worked for me perfectly.

Appreciated

Comment: Glad to be of help!